# Где сохранять файлы для приложения в Android?

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система

Создаю приложение для Android и не знаю куда сохранять файлы для своего приложения? Я хочу при запуске приложения создавать подпапку с картинками, шрифтом, музыкой в какой-нибудь всегда существующей папке. Также нужно будет чтобы и текстовые файлы сохранялись туда во время работы с приложением. Есть идеи?

Comment: На каком языке программирования вы пишете приложение?

Comment: На Python фреймворк Kivy

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage